# Android stopwatch lagging behind

Tags: android

I've made my own stop watch to run on am Android device and it all seems to be working well but after about 15-20 seconds there's a noticeable lag when being compared to other timers. I've been running it on an S4 mini and it uses 21% CPU, 1% memory and has 4 active threads running the entire time so I can't really see anything building up.

```
    public void onClick(View v){
    if(v == start)
    {
        started = true;
        reset.setClickable(false);
        task();

    }
    else if(v == stop){
        started = false;
        reset.setClickable(true);
    }
    else if(v == reset){
        timer = new Clock();
        hour.setText(Integer.toString(timer.getHour()));
        minute.setText(Integer.toString(timer.getMinute()));
        second.setText(Integer.toString(timer.getSecond()));
        milli.setText(Integer.toString(timer.getMilli()));
    }
}



public void task(){
    new Thread(new Runnable(){

        public void run(){
            while(started){


            try{

                timer.tick();

                layout.post(new Runnable(){

                    public void run(){
                        MainActivity.hour.setText(Integer.toString(timer.getHour()));
                        MainActivity.minute.setText(Integer.toString(timer.getMinute()));
                        MainActivity.second.setText(Integer.toString(timer.getSecond()));
                        MainActivity.milli.setText(Integer.toString(timer.getMilli()));
                        Log.v("thread", Integer.toString(Thread.activeCount()));
                    }
                });
                Thread.sleep(10);
            }
            catch(Exception e){

            }
            }


        }

    }).start();
}
```

Here's the contents of the Clock class

```
    public class Clock {
private int hour;
private int minute;
private int second;
private int milli;

Clock(int h, int m, int s, int mm) {
    hour = h;
    minute = m;
    second = s;
    milli = m;
}

Clock() {
    hour = 0;
    minute = 0;
    second = 0;
    milli = 0;
}

public void tick() {
    if (milli == 99) {
        milli = 0;
        if (second == 59) {
            second = 0;
            if (minute == 59) {
                minute = 0;
                if (hour == 23) {
                    hour = 0;
                } else {
                    hour++;
                }
            } else {
                minute++;
            }
        } else {
            second++;
        }
    } else {
        milli++;
    }
}

public int getHour() {
    return hour;
}

public int getMinute() {
    return minute;

}

public int getSecond() {
    return second;
}

public int getMilli() {
    return milli;
}
```

}

Comment: How do you maintain timer time within Clock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a horrible way to make a timer.  Thread.sleep has NO promises to accuracy-  it just means you'll sleep at least that much.  It could sleep 100x as much, if you aren't scheduled.  Use a timer, and even then you should double check the current time.  Linux is not a real time OS, and there is no promise that a scheduled timer will occur promptly.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I've implemented it again using a timer and timertask. However I'm still having the same issue, what do you mean by double check the current time?

Comment: Linux isn't a real time OS, it does not promise that a timer or sleep will return exactly when its supposed to, although a timer will likely do a better job.  You should still request the current time from the OS and calculate the amount of elapsed time rather than assume it is exact.